# Delegate protocols outside UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I'm new to programming and I find my self in a bit of a pickle. 
I'm contributing to an iOS application where the whole app is made out of views with the exception of the root View Controller. The views are called at run time and then destroyed when they are not in the view.
This is a first for me.

This is what my .h and .m files look like:

**.h File**

```
#ifndef PostPage_h
#define PostPage_h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

void * PostScreen();

#endif /* PostPage_h */
```

**.m File**

```
id MainScree()
{

id mainScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
    CGRect bounds = [mainScreen bounds];
    id containingView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height)];

UIView * mainView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height)];
mainView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[containingView addSubview:mainView];



 // Here is where all my images, buttons and labels are created and then added to the mainView. 

}
```

To test it, I pass the id inside the viewDidLoad of my rootViewController.
Everything works great so far! I can see my view and test it.

The problem I'm facing is that I also have a UITextView inside my id. 
And I need two delegate methods to add some functionality to it.

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView; {

        if ([textView.text isEqualToString:@"Place holder text"]) {
            textView.text = @"";
            textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }

        [textView becomeFirstResponder];

    }

-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView] {

    if ([textView.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        textView.text = @"Place holder text";
        textView.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    }

    [textView resignFirstResponder];

}
```

But it does not work. Xcode said: **Use of undeclared identifier 'textViewDidBeginEditing'**

Also it wont let me say

```
textView.delegate = self;
```

How can I find a solution for this? 
  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Let me make it clear that there in no view controllers, or interface builder in this app. Every view is created programmatically in code, created moments before the user sees it and destroyed after the user is done with it.

Comment: One more thing. h. file and m. file both have PostScreen(). Not PostScreen and MainScree().

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you declare a `<UITextViewDelegate>` in interface of your ViewController

in **ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController: UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
@end
```

or in **ViewController.m**

```
@interface ViewController() <UITextViewDelegate>
@end
```

Comment: I am not using ViewControllers. Every page view is created in one file and then called when even necessary.